# How configure daterange filter in SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have the next issue.
In admin class

```
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', array('field_type'=>'sonata_type_date_range_picker',))
            ;}
```

But when I try to apply it I have next error, seems it could not parse input filter fields and the filtering is not happening. Look at the screenshot  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoYkX.png) please.

Comment: Solution is 

->add(
    'createdAt',
    'doctrine_orm_date_range',
    [],
    'sonata_type_date_range_picker',
    [
        'field_options_start' => [
            'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
        ],
        'field_options_end' => [
            'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
        ]
    ]
)
maybe someone is help

Answer (score 0):

Mabey try to set format for this field (any). Like as:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', array(
            'field_type' => 'sonata_type_date_range_picker',
                'field_options' => [
                    'field_options' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                     ],
                ]
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: @Murilo: Please don't insert marks indicating where you edited an answer. You can add a comment explaining the edit if you feel it necessary, but putting extraneous stars in code is just as much a syntax error as the original.